# save_post vs post_updated

Tags: php, actions

I'm new to WordPress and php. I would like to write a function that triggers when a specific post has its content updated.

I came across 2 actions, `save_post` and `post_updated`. I'm a little confused as to when to use one over the other. I think the one I need is `post_updated`, but I'm not sure. I don't really know how to check if a specific post is updated. I haven't started much on it yet (at my non coding job), but here is what I have thought up so far, after looking at other suggestions:

```
add_action('post_updated', 'test_function');

function test_function($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before){

    //check if a specific post is updated here 

    $post_content = $post_after->post_content;

    $raw_data=array(
        'updated_post_content'=>$post_content,
    );

    //do something
}
```

Comment: `post_updated` is called when a post is updated whereas `save_post` is already called when the post is created. you can see that in reading the code : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3546

Comment: Note that if a post is created, it isn't updated. For a post to be updated it must already exist. But does this work for you? Or is this Q just looking for reassurance that you're doing it the correct way?

Answer (score 3):

OK, so let's start with Codex:

[`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

> is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated,
>   which could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc, or post by
>   email. The data for the post is stored in $_POST, $_GET or the global
>   $post_data, depending on how the post was edited. For example, quick
>   edits use $_POST.
>
> Since this action is triggered right after the post has been saved,
>   you can easily access this post object by using get_post($post_id).

It takes 3 params:

- $post_ID
- WP_Post $post (post object)
- bool $update (whether this is an existing post being updated or not.)

[`post_updated`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated)

> Use this hook whenever you need to compare values before and after the
>   post update.
>
> This hook pass up to 3 arguments, as follows:
>
> - $post_ID ;
> - $post_after (post object after the update);
> - $post_before (post object before the update);

### So when should you use which one of them?

`post_updated` is fired up only if the given post existed before and currently is updated. It won't get called, when a new post is inserted. It is very useful, if you want to do something with previous version of given post.

`save_post` is fired up whenever a post is saved. You don't have easy access to previous version of given post in here (you'll have to use revisions, if they're available).

### And some more confusion ;)

There is also one more action, you can use:

- `save_post_{$post->post_type}` with the same params as `save_post`, it's fired up just before `save_post` and you can use it, if you want to run your code only for given post type.